# how do i run length encode a pattern, rather than a character?

Tags: python, python-3.x

heres my current RLE code

```
import re

def decode(string):
    if string == '':
        return ''
    multiplier = 1
    count = 0
    rle_decoding = []

    rle_encoding = []     
    rle_encoding = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]|-?\d+\.\d+|\d+|[\w\s]', string) 
    for item in rle_encoding:
        if item.isdigit():
            multiplier = int(item)
        elif item.isalpha() or item.isspace():
            while count < multiplier:
                rle_decoding.append('{0}'.format(item))
                count += 1
            multiplier = 1
            count = 0 
    return(''.join(rle_decoding))
def encode(string):
    if string == '':
        return ''
    i = 0
    count = 0
    letter = string[i]
    rle = []
    while i <= len(string) - 1:        
        while string[i] == letter:
            i+= 1
            count +=1
            #catch the loop on last character so it doesn't got to top and access out of bounds
            if i > len(string) - 1:
                break
        if count == 1:
            rle.append('{0}'.format(letter))
        else:
            rle.append('{0}{1}'.format(count, letter))
        if i > len(string) - 1: #ugly that I have to do it twice
            break
        letter = string[i]
        count = 0

    final = ''.join(rle)
    return final
```

the code might have gotten fucked up when I removed all my comments, but the current code isn't too important. the problem is, I am running RLE on hexadecimal values, that have all been converted to letters so that 0-9 becomes g-p. the problem is that there are a lot of patterns like 'kjkjkjkjkjkjkjkjlmlmlmlmlmlmlm' which doesn't compress at all, because of their not single characters. how would I, if even possible, be able to run my program so that it encodes patterns as well?

Comment: You could do RLE with a larger chunk-size than 1. If you try to use variable-length chunk size, you probably aren't talking about pure RLE  anymore. There are numerous compression algorithms, some will be able to exploit larger repeated chunks.

Comment: if you are just after compression, zip or 7z would work on bigger chunksizes automagically